# $.ajax with view is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I want to call a method of a controller which is not an action method in a view through `$.ajax` but I am getting error in browser console. I want to ask that is it not possible to call a method which is not action method through ajax.

Code for view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxcall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/ValidatePin',
            type: 'Post',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
<h2>About</h2>
<p>
    Put content here.

    <input type="button" onclick="ajaxcall()"  value="clickme" />
</p>
```

Here is my code for method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Services;
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string ValidatePin()
        {
            return "returned from controller class";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am getting error in browser console` what is it?

Comment: i mean error on debugging through f12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All public methods of a controller are actions, unless marked with the [`NonAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute.

The `[WebMethod]` attribute comes from ASP.NET web services (non MVC) and has no effect in an MVC controller.

Your `ValidatePin` method is not called because it's static. Action methods must be instance methods.

Comment: but is it necessary to create a  method with returntype actionresult

Comment: @user1929135 No it's not. A `string` will do if you actually want a string.

Comment: Actually, there are a tonne of types you can return other than ActionResult, such as JsonResult (my preference in this case would be JSON over a raw string). Have a look at http://brendan.enrick.com/post/types-of-aspnet-mvc-3-action-results.aspx, in particular the JsonResult section.